# Emoticon on Text, Python

Tags: python, tkinter, emoticons

How may I put Emoticons inside a text widget?

My code doesn't seem to work.

```
    self.emote=[]
    self.emote.append("logo.gif")
    self.txtentermsg.image_create(END, image=self.emote[0])
```

`txtentermsg` is a text widget.

Comment: The answers on that question doesn't work on me.

Comment: Then please edit your question to explain what you've tried, provide an example that actually recreates the issue and be more specific than *"doesn't work"* - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Ahhh that gives me an idea! Thanks :)